# Convert *.xls to *csv with C++

Tags: c++, qt, csv, xls, qprocess

I'm trying to convert a xls(x) file to csv in C++ using QProcess::start()

```
QProcess *myProcess = new QProcess();
myProcess->start("path/xls2csv.exe fileName.xlsx > fileName.csv");
```

There is no error message, but nothing happens.

When I start the xls2csv in cmd with the Line:

```
xls2csv.exe fileName.xls > fileName.csv
```

Everything works fine.

I also tried to attach the file names in a QStringList as argument, but that doesn't work either.

The Excel File is in the same directory like the xls2csv.exe.

I appreciate any help!

Comment: Is fileName.xlsx and fileName.csv exist at running path? Or it`s located at xls2csv path?

Comment: fileName.xlsx is located at xls2csv path, fileName.xsv isn't created yet. It should be created when I run the executable

Comment: change you code to `myProcess->setWorkingDirector("PATH_XLS2CSV"); myProcess->start("xls2csv.exe fileName.xlsx > fileName.csv");`